# IFNULL não está funcionando

Tags: mysql

```
    select IFNULL(valor_unit,0) from tb_itens where id = 3
```

No cenário onde o **id = 3** não existe na minha `table` o `SELECT` não retorna '0' apenas continua retornando NULL,
não consigo encontrar o problema.
Já testei com `COALESCE`, porém continua retornando null.

Answer (score 5):

> No cenário onde o id = 3 não existe na minha table o SELECT não
>   retorna '0' apenas continua retornando NULL

Com certeza, a função vai verificar o valor do campo, mas se você já limitou no `where`, não trazendo o que pode ser nulo porque não existe, não vai vir o resultado.

A função `isnull` deve ser usando quando um valor pode vir nulo, se remover o `where` deve trazer o resultado correto.

Comment: Uhm, entendi. Achei que, ao não encontrar algum valor, justamento pela condição where imposta, ele me retornaria null (no caso '0').  Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, faz sentido seu raciocínio, mas como o `where` é processado antes do `select`, que só retorna o que foi filtrado, nunca vai chegar a processar um null :)